# Security checks on PHP (with PDO) for a member authentication and registration

Tags: php, pdo, xss, security

I'm looking for an examples of some more advanced security checks that I'd be able to perform on my website.

I'm using PHP 5.2 with PDO MySQL database.

What would interest me most are:

- samples of SQL injections that work with default PDO inserts/updates (yes, I am using prepare),
- any checks that would allow me to see if my script doesn't display the table names anywhere in the code (including PHP exceptions),
- any ways of killing or hacking user accounts in the database either through the registration forms or authentication forms (that said - I already have brute-force protection on login form).

I'd be also interested in performing live checks on any attempts of session hijacking or cross-site scripting (I have textareas that allow users to input the HTML code (through TINY MCE) and I'd like to know if my mechanics prevent any well-known XSS attacks).

Any samples would be appreciated :) Especially these related to SQL injections into the PDO.

Comment: The title would be better: 'Security checks on PHP tools'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you this tools, is a scanner that check your site for vulnerabilites and marks you file and line number among with kind of vulnerability and also how to solve it.
You download the files and put them in your web server it is meant to be used only local please do not use it in a real live site:

http://rips-scanner.sourceforge.net/

Here are more (I have not tried them):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpsecaudit/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/yasca/

Hope this helps you.
Regards